# Why is TextInput updating after I hit fileReferencer.browse button a second time

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textinput, filereference

In Flex 4, I am trying to make a simple browse button update the text field of an TextInput object with the file name that the browse button gets. It doesn't have to be the full path, all I want is the file name to show up. It only shows up after hitting the browse button for a second time, not after I have selected my file the first time. Here is my code:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;

        private var fileReferencer:FileReference = new FileReference();
        private var excelFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("*.xlsx", "*.xlsx;*.xls;");
        protected var fileName:String = new String("");

        protected function BrowseButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            fileReferencer.browse([excelFilter]);
            fileName = fileReferencer.name;
            fileInputAddress.text = fileName;
        }
```

So to recap, the file name is only shown in my TextInput box upon hitting the browse button a second time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't put tags (AKA Flex 4) in the title of your post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player is completely asynchronous. So you can't get file name right after calling `fileReferencer.browse()`. That's why you have a name from the past call. To fix your code you should subscribe on `select` and `cancel` events and change the text after `select` event only (see [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29)).

Comment: Just as you were answering this I found a blog post that uses your exact answer. Thank you so much for your help. If anyone is interested in that link, it is [here](http://dgrigg.com/blog/2007/08/02/Flex-and-Flash-file-uploading-with-return-data/)